# Can an element occupy one CSS grid row and a subelement occupy one of the row's cells?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'd like to achieve the following effect:

```css
.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 2rem 10rem / auto 20rem auto;
}

.a {
  background: orange;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.b {
  background: green;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.c {
  background: lightblue;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 2;
  
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b">Title</div>
    <div class="c">This is section C.</div>
  </div>
```

but using the following HTML instead:

```
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="a"><div class="b">Title</div></div>
    <div class="c">This is section C.</div>
  </div>
```

where `.b` is inside `.a`.

In other words, I'd like for element `.a` to occupy the top row of a CSS grid, but have one of its subelements, `.b`, to occupy only the middle cell of this same CSS grid row. Is this possible?

Comment: you can achieve using css position

Answer (score 1):

Apply `display:grid` and `grid-template: 2rem 10rem / auto 20rem auto;` to `a`, check this

```css
.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 2rem 10rem / auto 20rem auto;
}

.a {
  background: orange;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 2rem 10rem / auto 20rem auto;
}

.b {
  background: green;
  grid-column: 2/ 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.c {
  background: lightblue;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 2;
  
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrap">
    <div class="a"><div class="b">Title</div></div>
    <div class="c">This is section C.</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: So I have to have nested grids?

Answer (score 0):

That will work just fine in the future by defining display: subgrid in class .a...
But support is still very limited.
https://gridbyexample.com/video/subgrid-display-contents/

```css
.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 2rem 10rem / auto 20rem auto;
}

.a {
  background: orange;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 1;
  display: subgrid;
}

.b {
  background: green;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.c {
  background: lightblue;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 2;
  
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="a">
    <div class="b">Title</div></div>
    <div class="c">This is section C.</div>
  </div>
```